# Ubuntu server is randomly having large time sync issues

Tags: ubuntu, ntp

It seems that randomly the time on my server will jump forward several hours. This happens randomly and the only way I've found to fix it is to manually force an NTP call. I don't see anything out of place in my ntp.conf and I can't seem to find anything that would suggest WHY this is happening.

The last 3 times this has happened are:

- 2014-10-08: Time offset by -17593 seconds
- 2014-12-30: Time offset by -13196 seconds
- 2015-01-01: Time offset by -30783 seconds

As you can see, the dates are seemingly random as is the amount the clock is off by. This has been happening for approximately the last year at random intervals. I only know of these because I have added cron jobs to forcefully ensure the date gets reset daily, which is not a good or ideal solution.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to where I could look to see what is causing this random drift? This is a virtual private server.

I have attached my ntp.conf in case this will help.

```
# /etc/ntp.conf, configuration for ntpd; see ntp.conf(5) for help

driftfile /var/lib/ntp/ntp.drift


# Enable this if you want statistics to be logged.
#statsdir /var/log/ntpstats/

statistics loopstats peerstats clockstats
filegen loopstats file loopstats type day enable
filegen peerstats file peerstats type day enable
filegen clockstats file clockstats type day enable

# Specify one or more NTP servers.

# Use servers from the NTP Pool Project. Approved by Ubuntu Technical Board
# on 2011-02-08 (LP: #104525). See http://www.pool.ntp.org/join.html for
# more information.
server 0.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org
server 1.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org
server 2.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org
server 3.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org

# Use Ubuntu's ntp server as a fallback.
server ntp.ubuntu.com

# Access control configuration; see /usr/share/doc/ntp-doc/html/accopt.html for
# details.  The web page <http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Support/AccessRestrictions>
# might also be helpful.
#
# Note that "restrict" applies to both servers and clients, so a configuration
# that might be intended to block requests from certain clients could also end
# up blocking replies from your own upstream servers.

# By default, exchange time with everybody, but don't allow configuration.
restrict -4 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery
restrict -6 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery

# Local users may interrogate the ntp server more closely.
restrict 127.0.0.1
restrict ::1

# Clients from this (example!) subnet have unlimited access, but only if
# cryptographically authenticated.
#restrict 192.168.123.0 mask 255.255.255.0 notrust


# If you want to provide time to your local subnet, change the next line.
# (Again, the address is an example only.)
#broadcast 192.168.123.255

# If you want to listen to time broadcasts on your local subnet, de-comment the
# next lines.  Please do this only if you trust everybody on the network!
#disable auth
#broadcastclient
```

Comment: Is this a physical server or a virtual one?

Comment: It's a virtual server.

Comment: Depending on the virtualisation type the host may be doing something to the clock and running a ntp daemon may be what is interfering in the first place. What virtualisation type is being used?

Comment: Contact your provider. The host clock is probably wrong.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I'll start by contacting my provider. I wondered if that could be it.